# AngularJs, expressions aren't showing up

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm sorry if this question has been repeated but I still can't seem to find the solution for this. This is my first experience with AngularJS so please bear with me.

my simple html:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular Practice</title>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/controller.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="simple">
    <h1>{{ author.name }}</h1>
    <p>{{ author.title }}</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the controller.js that I got from AngularJS's tutorial:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('simple', function ($scope) {
    $scope.author = [
       {'name': 'Parker',
        'title': 'Full Stack Developer'}
   ];
});
```

Then when I go on the browser on my html, it's a blank.

Comment: What you have is an array. So `author[0].name` should work, seems like you just need an object so change it to `$scope.author = 
       {'name': 'Parker',
        'title': 'Full Stack Developer'}` and access the way you have

Comment: @PSL maybe you should post your comment as an answer. I was just about posting the same stuff as an answer when read your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your $scope you have the `author` property, that is an array.
If you access like you're doing, with `author.name`, it won't work because you are trying to access the `name` property in the array object, that doesn't have a `name` property.

So, I would suggest you changing it to:

```
$scope.author = {
    name: 'Parker',
    title: 'Full Stack Developer'
};
```

Also, accessing like

```
{{ author[0].name }}
```

would also work, but it doesn't make sense to have an array here where you want to have, apparently, only one object.